# Skinning a scroll bar in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, scrollbar

I am working on a WPF project using VS2010 and .NET 4.0. I have custom PNG graphics for the various pieces of a vertical scroll bar. My goal is to create my own custom skin for the vertical scroll bars in my application.

I chose WPF for this over Winforms because I was told skinning was a trivial matter. Upon searching for existing topics covering this, I found this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx

From the looks of it, it's fairly complex to skin a scroll bar. I'm still learning WPF and I have yet to understand most of the concepts, such as templates, triggers, data binding, etc. I'm trying to learn by hands on experience. For my specific case, does the above MSDN article pretty much outline what is required to skin a scroll bar? Is there no cleaner, more trivial method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should try Expression Blend as it is much easier to modify styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reference material the link you provided is adequate. A more scholastic approach by Sacha can be viewed [here](http://sachabarber.net/?p=122) which makes use of the base style which your link references.

Styling varies greatly; from merely changing a color to changing the entire look and feel. Modifying existing templates is a good place to start as you begin to uncover the concepts and parts associated with template's within the WPF framework. Editing a style can be trivial however it can also become extremely complex. This is all contingent on the desired outcome.